# Php - omo cerrar sesion en todas las pestañas abiertas

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en php CodeIgniter, y necesito proteger los datos.

Por ejemplo, un dentista abre en otra pestaña su lista de pacientes, luego cierra sesion, la pestaña donde dio esta orden destruye todas las variables session y vuelve a la pagina de logueo.
Pero sigue abierta la pestaña de la lista de pacientes. Está claro que la sesión se destruye en todo el navegador, pero que pasa si otro dentista se loguea en el mismo navegador y PC (suponiendo los peores casos), se vuelven a crear las variables session, y logra ver la pestaña de la lista de pacientes del otro dentista y tambien realizar acciones en ella.

De que manera se puede implementar una seguridad para esto, había pensado en que se cierren todas las pestañas abiertas de este sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es que cada vez que se inicie sesión creara una Cookie con el identificador del usuario. (Por ejemplo)

```
setcookie("idusuario", $_SESSION['idusuario']);
```

Entonces cada vez que se haga uso del sistema, comparas si existe la cookie y si su identificador es igual al de la variable de sesión, si esta condición no se cumple lo envías al cierre de sesión.:

```
if(issset($_COKKIE['idusuario'])!=$_SESSION['idusuario'] ){
   header('Location: ../logout');
}
```

Edito:

Para crear una cookie en codeigniter utilizas lo siguiente:

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'The Cookie Name',
    'value'  => 'The Value',
    'expire' => '86500',
    'domain' => '.example.com',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
    'secure' => TRUE
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```